# Massive amount of objects / characters in Blender

Tags: modeling, procedural

Coming from the Maya world, I had plugins to generate massive amount of objects with minimal impact on performance (like Miarmy or Golaem), and had zillion of options to place and animate them. Do such plugins exist on Blender ?

I am trying to reproduce such kind of concepts:

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at Geometry nodes (included) and animation nodes (not included, but free)

Comment: Blender has particle systems and old boid-particles.

Comment: That looks amazing, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help provided, I could investigate the Geometry nodes and outcome is barely great for a simple implementation.
[image]